# Trying to update twitter using twidge in python

Tags: python, linux, twitter

I am trying to tweet from python using twidge. My script looks like this 
`import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", "twidge", "update", "Trying tweeting from linux python - twidge."])` 
I am getting the error 
`twidge: user error (No config file found at /root/.twidgerc
Run twidge setup to configure twidge for use.)` 
And I have already configured twidge and it works in bash.
I am sorry if I am unspecific please ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `sudo`? You should be able to run `twidge` as a non-privileged user.

Answer (score 0):

It it likely that your existing `.twidgerc` file is in a different location.

By default, twidge will look for the configuration file in the current user's home directory (see `man twidge`). Since you are using `sudo`, it is looking for `.twidgerc` in root's home directory.

You can specify an alternate location using the `-c` or `--config` flags:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", 
                 "twidge", 
                 "--config=/path/to/.twidgerc", 
                 "update", 
                 "Trying tweeting from linux python - twidge."])
```